# Como somar valores de um campo agrupado por data?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

```
SELECT funcionario_id, data, avaliacao_postura FROM equipe
```

```
id  funcionario_id  data           avaliacao_postura            
1   1               2014-03-02     -25;-10;-5;-12           
2   1               2014-03-01     -25;-10;-18          
3   1               2014-03-02     -25;-15;-14
```

Preciso fazer um select que me retorne a soma do campo `avaliacao_postura` fazendo a soma em todas as data iguais e em negativo e o resultado agrupado por data. O resultado teria que ser como neste exemplo:

```
funcionario_id  data           avaliacao_postura
1               2014-03-02     -106
1               2014-03-01     -53
```

Comment: Seria bem simples, não fosse a necessidade de somar na horizontal os valores dentro de `avaliacao_postura`, que é texto e não numérico.

Answer (score 5):

Eu mudaria o design dessa tabela. Da maneira que dados estão armazenados agora você não consegue trazer nenhuma informação básica referente as avaliações.

Um exemplo de uma nova estrutura:

```
                    date           smallint NOT NULL
id  funcionario_id  data           avaliacao_postura            
1   1               2014-03-02     -25
2   1               2014-03-02     -10   
3   1               2014-03-02     -5   
4   1               2014-03-02     -12             
5   1               2014-03-01     -25  
6   1               2014-03-01     -10  
7   1               2014-03-01     -18          
8   1               2014-03-02     -25
9   1               2014-03-02     -15
10  1               2014-03-02     -14
```

Dessa maneira você consegue o resultado esperado com uma simples query.

```
SELECT funcionario_id, data, SUM(avaliacao_postura) as avaliacao_postura
FROM equipe
GROUP BY funcionario_id, data
```

Comment: Esse é o modelo que eu teria feito deste o inicio ...

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma View no mesmo banco dessa tabela com esse Script ( é só rodar esse trecho ):

```
Create View iterator (x) as
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6;
```

Logo Após rode essa SQL:

```
SELECT funcionario_id, data, sum(avaliacao_postura) avaliacao_postura  from
(
select 
    substring_index(
        substring_index(equipe.avaliacao_postura,';',iter.x), ';', -1) 
        AS avaliacao_postura, equipe.data, equipe.funcionario_id
from equipe, iterator iter
     where iter.x <= length(equipe.avaliacao_postura)-length(
        replace(equipe.avaliacao_postura,';',''))+1 order by equipe.data, iter.x) AS C
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY data
```

É uma forma razoável e que funcionou...

Se eu fosse você mudaria o layout da sua tabela para compor a cada linha um item do avaliacao_postura, mas, esse rotina vai estraindo item a item dentro da string separada por `;` e relaciona com os itens da View iterator.

Comment: Você pode incluir uma explicação? Sua solução funciona, ao menos para esse caso, mas o funcionamento do método que você usou não é óbvio.

Comment: @bfavaretto, essa solução foi a base de pesquisa, e realmente ela funciona, eu não faria assim eu faria um linha para cada dado de avaliacao_postura, ou seja, mudaria o layout da tabela ...

Comment: Entendo (eu também usaria outro layout), mas como você achou um jeito que nem requer chamada de função MySQL, seria legal para a comunidade que esse método fosse explicado em detalhes. É sempre recomendado incluir explicações nas respostas, e levar em consideração que sua resposta não é somente para quem fez a pergunta, e sim um conteúdo que pode vir a ajudar muitos outros futuros visitantes do site. Eu pessoalmente considero a explicação até mais importante que o código que resolve o problema, por ser mais genérica.

Comment: Aproveitando, segue um demo da sua solução: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a97d6/1

Comment: muito obrigado resolveu o meu problema, pensei que seria mais simples mais ja vi que nao.